# How do you configure a github organization's repo to send notification emails about all events?

Tags: github, email-notifications

The [webhooks guide](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) lists email as one of the available services, however it seems that this only kicks off when a user actually pushes a change to the repository. How can you configure it so that an email is fired off for every event concerning that repo - issues opened/closed, pull requests, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, currently. See [this pull request](https://github.com/github/github-services/pull/284) to the github-services which would enable at least pull request notification by email, but it was never merged by GitHub.

As a work-around I currently use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) on my Android device to get notified about pull requests by email.